# How to get a derive 'N' Date Rows from a single record with From / To date columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Title sounds confusing but let me please explain:

I have a table that has two columns that provide a date range, and one column that provides a value. I need to query that table and "detail" the data such as this

[image]

Is it possible to do only using TSQL?

**Additional Info**

The table in question is about 2-3million records long (and growing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the range of dates is fairly narrow, an alternative is to use a recursive CTE to create a list of all dates in the range and then join interpolate to it:

```
WITH LastDay AS
(
  SELECT MAX(Date_To) AS MaxDate
  FROM MyTable
),
Days AS
(
  SELECT MIN(Date_From) AS TheDate
  FROM MyTable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, TheDate) AS TheDate
  FROM Days CROSS JOIN LastDay
  WHERE TheDate <= LastDay.MaxDate
)
SELECT mt.Item_ID, mt.Cost_Of_Item, d.TheDate
FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN Days d
ON d.TheDate BETWEEN mt.Date_From AND mt.Date_To;
```

I've also assumed an that date from and date to represent an inclusive range (i.e. includes both edges) - it is unusual to use inclusive `BETWEEN` on dates.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f272f/3)

**Edit**

The default `MAXRECURSION` on a recursive CTE in Sql Server is 100, which will limit the date range in the query to a span of 100 days. You can adjust this to a [maximum of 32767](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms175972.aspx).

Also, if you are filtering just a smaller range of dates in your large table, you can adjust the CTE to limit the number of days in the range:

```
WITH DateRange AS
(
  SELECT CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE) AS MinDate, 
         CAST('2014-02-16' AS DATE) AS MaxDate
),
Days AS
(
  SELECT MinDate AS TheDate
  FROM DateRange

  UNION ALL

  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, TheDate) AS TheDate
  FROM Days CROSS APPLY DateRange
  WHERE TheDate <= DateRange.MaxDate
)
SELECT mt.Item_ID, mt.Cost_Of_Item, d.TheDate
FROM MyTable mt
INNER JOIN Days d
ON d.TheDate BETWEEN mt.Date_From AND mt.Date_To
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[Update Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f272f/6)

Comment: thank you for your answer, tried the Fiddle, worked great, tried on my server... not so much... forgot to say that the table is 2mill records long and when executing the code I get a 530 error. Working to better understand your query to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Seemingly the date range in the data is greater than 100 days - I've updated with some more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `Cursors`.

I've simulated the test data provided and created another table with the name "DesiredTable" to store the data inside, and created the following cusror which achieved exactly what you are looking for:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ITEM_ID int, @COST_OF_ITEM Money,
        @DATE_FROM date, @DATE_TO date;

DECLARE @DateDiff INT; -- holds number of days between from & to columns
DECLARE @counter INT = 0; -- for loop counter

PRINT '-------- Begin the Date Expanding Cursor --------';

-- defining the cursor target statement
DECLARE Date_Expanding_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT [ITEM_ID]
      ,[COST_OF_ITEM]
      ,[DATE_FROM]
      ,[DATE_TO]
  FROM [dbo].[OriginalTable]

-- openning the cursor
OPEN Date_Expanding_Cursor

-- fetching next row data into the declared variables
FETCH NEXT FROM Date_Expanding_Cursor 
INTO @ITEM_ID, @COST_OF_ITEM, @DATE_FROM, @DATE_TO

-- if next row is found
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

-- calculate the number of days in between the date columns
SELECT @DateDiff = DATEDIFF(day,@DATE_FROM,@DATE_TO)

-- reset the counter to 0 for the next loop
set @counter = 0;

WHILE @counter <= @DateDiff
BEGIN

-- inserting rows inside the new table
insert into DesiredTable
Values (@COST_OF_ITEM, DATEADD(day,@counter,@DATE_FROM))

set @counter = @counter +1
END

-- fetching next row
FETCH NEXT FROM Date_Expanding_Cursor 
INTO @ITEM_ID, @COST_OF_ITEM, @DATE_FROM, @DATE_TO
END

-- cleanup code
CLOSE Date_Expanding_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE Date_Expanding_Cursor;
```

The code fetches every row from your original table, then it calculates the number of days between `DATE_FROM` and `DATE_TO` columns, then using this number the script will create identical rows to be inserted inside the new table `DesiredTable`.

give it a try and let me know of the results.

Comment: It works as a charm, thank you. Only an issue: the table in question is about 2-3million records long (and growing), so the use of a cursor is really resource heavy and it takes a long time to complete.

Comment: ooh, sorry about that. I didn't know this information when I created this solution. forgive me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an increment table and join it to your date From:

> **Query:**

```
With inc(n) as (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) -1 From (
        Select 1 From (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
    ) as x(n)
)
Select item_id, cost, DATEADD(day, n, dateFrom), n From @dates d
Inner Join inc i on n <= DATEDIFF(day, dateFrom, dateTo) 
Order by item_id
```

> **Output:**

```
item_id cost    Date                        n
1       100     2014-01-01 00:00:00.000     0
1       100     2014-01-02 00:00:00.000     1
1       100     2014-01-03 00:00:00.000     2
2       105     2014-01-08 00:00:00.000     2
2       105     2014-01-07 00:00:00.000     1
2       105     2014-01-06 00:00:00.000     0
2       105     2014-01-09 00:00:00.000     3
3       102     2014-02-14 00:00:00.000     3
3       102     2014-02-15 00:00:00.000     4
3       102     2014-02-16 00:00:00.000     5
3       102     2014-02-11 00:00:00.000     0
3       102     2014-02-12 00:00:00.000     1
3       102     2014-02-13 00:00:00.000     2
```

> **Sample Data:**

```
declare @dates table(item_id int, cost int, dateFrom datetime, dateTo datetime);
insert into @dates(item_id, cost, dateFrom, dateTo) values
(1, 100, '20140101', '20140103')
, (2, 105, '20140106', '20140109')
, (3, 102, '20140211', '20140216');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to create and maintain calendar table, containing all dates for many years (in our app we have table for 30 years or so, extending every year). Then you can just link to calendar:

```
select <whatever you need>, calendar.day
from <your tables> inner join calendar on calendar.day between <min date> and <max date>
```

This approach allows to include additional information (holidays etc) in calendar table - sometimes very helpful.